# Different results for opencv c++ kmeans and matlab kmeans

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

MATLAB K-means gives accurate results for an image, whereas k-means with OpenCV c++ does not give the same result, even though parameters are same. Is there any difference in implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Matlab's [`kmeans` function](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html) uses kmeans++ by default, and kmeans++ can be activated in [cv::kmeans](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/d38/group__core__cluster.html#ga9a34dc06c6ec9460e90860f15bcd2f88) through the [`KMEANS_PP_CENTERS`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d0/de1/group__core.html#ga276000efe55ee2756e0c471c7b270949) flag.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) that method **randomly** chooses k-observations from the data set and uses these as the initial means.  And the result may depend on the initial clusters

That's why results may differ even within OpenCV methods execution, especially for Matlab